# How is a draft removed since looks like only option is continued

Tags: email

How to remove more than 1 draft since only option appears to be "continued"?

Comment: Pls provide more information when asking questions. Experience has shown that people who are trying to help other people on this site are not all endowed with great mind reading abilities

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given much information but I assume you are refering to bulk emails under civimail.  After creating a draft bulk email, there is the option to continue with it or delete it.  Look under Mailings>Draft and unscheduled mailings>Action column, where you will see a 'Delete' option.

Hope this helps.